# Issues when installing strapi plugin redirects

Tags: plugins, strapi

I'm getting the following error when trying to install this plugin strapi-plugin-redirects:

Any ideas?

Environment -

```
Strapi version "4.13.6".
```

```
Node version: v18.16.0
```

Using the following to install

```
npm i strapi-plugin-redirects
```

Error -

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: appname@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @amicaldo/strapi-google-maps@1.1.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@amicaldo/strapi-google-maps
npm ERR!     @amicaldo/strapi-google-maps@"^1.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.13.1 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@5.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react
npm ERR!     @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@"^5.0.6" from @_sh/strapi-plugin-ckeditor@2.0.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@_sh/strapi-plugin-ckeditor
npm ERR!       @_sh/strapi-plugin-ckeditor@"^2.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   90 more (@emotion/react, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! strapi-plugin-redirects@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.2" from strapi-plugin-redirects@0.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/strapi-plugin-redirects
npm ERR!     strapi-plugin-redirects@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/<my_dir>/.npm/_logs/2023-12-04T09_36_00_517Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/<my_dir>/.npm/_logs/2023-12-04T09_36_00_517Z-debug-0.log
```